# Can't connect Spark and Scala 2.11 to MongoDB with SSL with .pem configuration

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have a problem when connecting from scala & spark application to Mongodb although I did on C# successful.

```
            My C# code:
            var url = "mongodb://user:pass@servername:27017/admin?ssl=true";
            var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(url));
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MIID5TCCAs2gAwIBAgIJANoGBQADggEBAHaIdU9ri.....");
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
            clientSettings.SslSettings = new SslSettings
            {
                ClientCertificates = new[] { cert },
                CheckCertificateRevocation = false
            };

            clientSettings.UseSsl = true;
            clientSettings.VerifySslCertificate = false;
            var client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
            database = client.GetDatabase("databasename");
```

I searched the office mongodb drive document but it's quite different for each version and all of them is not right. Could you please advice with connection with Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.3? My mongodb prod is configured using .pem file.

Thank you very much! 
Trinh

Answer (score 1):

The SSL config for Spark <-> MongoDB is not very well documented.
In essence you need to add truststore & keystore config to your driver & executor config, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-115

So you need to add that config to your spark-submit command eg: 
`--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_trustStore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustPassword -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keyStore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keyPassword"`

And you need to add the `crt` (first part of your `.pem` probably) to the keystore, like:

`keytool -alias mongodb -importcert -trustcacerts -file mongodb.crt -keystore path_to_keyStore -storepass keyPassword`

If you find a better solution, please let me know

Comment: Thanks Tom for your support. I am trying to connect with development tool like  IDEA first. Do you have any documents to help connect with IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Just add them in the VM options (without the `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=`)